# Amazon Route 53 Client Exception on creation

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a problem with amazon sdk for .net while creating an Amazon Route 53 Client calling

```
AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonRoute53Client(AccessKeyID, SecretAccessKeyID);
```

I get an Exception that tells

> "No RegionEndPoint or ServiceURL configured".

Also tried the region endpoint indicated there http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#r53_region with no result.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: what is your config file like? and how are you setting it the Service URL's to access?

Comment: I'm following this tutorial :)

http://derpturkey.com/amazon-route53-c-examples/

and this

https://gist.github.com/j3tm0t0/2024833

Answer (score 41):

I had the same problem when using

```
objClient = New AmazonS3Client(AccessKeyID, SecretAccessKeyID)
```

I solved using:

```
objClient = New AmazonS3Client(AccessKeyID, SecretAccessKeyID, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1)
```

(My s3 was the USEast1 = US Standard)

Comment: This corrected my issue! It came up after upgrading to the latest AWS SDK.

Answer (score 14):

Try this!

```
AmazonS3Config S3Config = new AmazonS3Config()
{
    ServiceURL = "s3.amazonaws.com",
    RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.SAEast1
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding the BasicAWS Credentials, and link it to say AmazonDynamoDBClient web services, you can write it like this.

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyHere, secretKeyHere);

AmazonDynamoDBConfig adcConfig = new AmazonDynamoDBConfig()
{
    ServiceURL = "s3.amazonaws.com",
    RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1
};

AmazonDynamoDB client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(awsCredentials, adcConfig);
```

For the AmazonS3 web service, you will write: -

```
AmazonS3Config asConfig = new AmazonS3Config()
{
    ServiceURL = "s3.amazonaws.com",
    RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1
};

AmazonS3Client client2 = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials, asConfig);
```